# Compare growth rate: n·lg(n) and 0.02·n^(1.01). Which one grows faster?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science

Comparing `n·lg(n)` and `0.02·n^(1.01)`, which one grows faster?

I could write `n^(1.01)` as `n·n^(0.01)`.

Doing that, the question becomes then: how to compare `lg(n)` and `n^0.01`.

But I don't know which one of `lg(n)` and `n^0.01` grows faster.

How could I solve the problem?

Comment: Try for values of n=10, n=10^20, n=10^200, n=10^300. Make a graph if needed.

Comment: How's your calculus? Consider trying L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: You can use the fact that for positive>1 numbers, `log(x)>log(y)` iif `x>y`. Take log from both sides and you get : `log(nlog(n)) = log(n) + log(log(n) ?? log(0.02·n^(1.01)) = log(0.02) + 1.01 log(n)`. From here it should be pretty clear which is dominating.

Answer (score 2):

The logarithm grows slower than any positive power. Assuming that `lg` is decimal logarithm, `0.02 n^(1.01)` will exceed `n lg(n)` at `n ~= 4.04192e+433` (see [Wolphram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28n*lg+n+%3D+0.02+*+n+%5E+1.01%29) query). If it's practical problem about computational complexity though, it's likely that for reasonable `n` values, `0.02 n^(1.01)` algorithm will be faster than `n lg(n)` algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

To see witch function is growing faster, you can calculate the limit

```
lim f(n)/g(n)
```

If the limit is `0`, `g(n)` grows faster than `f(n)`, if it is `∞`, `f(n)` grows faster than `g(n)` and if it is any other number they grow both the same way.

to calculate such a limit [L'Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) can be helpful. It says

```
lim f(n)/g(n) = lim f'(n)/g'(n)
```

where `f'(n)` is the differentiation of `f(n)`.

In your case you have to calculate

```
lim n0.01/ln n = lim (1/n0.99)/(1/n) = lim n/n0.99 = lim n0.01 = ∞
```

So `n0.01` grows faster than `ln n`.